# Как сделать медиа-запрос адаптации сайта, если я сначала верстал сайт под ноутбук?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Я изначально верстал сайт с ноутбука, поэтому теперь мне нужно сделать адаптацию под компьютер и остальные устройства. Все видео и статьи которые нашёл в интернете начинали с компьютерной версии. Возможно я просто неправильно использую (min-width). Всё остальное получилось только с (max-width). Буду очень благодарен, если объясните и поможете мне с этим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Селайте много запросов по типу:

min-width 1920 (для экранов больше 1920)
max-width 1919 and min-width 1800(для экранов в даиапазоне 1919-1800)
(1400-1800)
(1000-1399)
(800-999)
(450-799)
(320-449)
Определите в каком из диапазонов находится экран вашего ноутбука и поместите весь css туда, для всех остальных дополняйте

Пример вашего медиазапроса: `@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px)`